# Como podría optimizar una carga de datos en Android

Tags: android

Primero decir que no soy una experta en aplicaciones android. Soy totalmente autodidacta en esto. Profesionalmente soy desarrolladora pero de AS400 con Cobol y RPG (lenguajes totalmente secuenciales). Lo de las Apps es un hobby. Por eso disculparme si no sé explicarme muy adecuadamente en el lenguaje correcto.

Mi problema es que tengo este método para cargar un array con los datos de una determinada tabla

```
    public void getMessges(final List<SMS> listsms, final String tableName) {

    int count = 0;
    Cursor cur = null;

    if(tableName == "SMS_INBOX"){
          cur =  SMS_INBOX.fetchAllINBOX();
    }
    if(tableName == "SMS_SENT"){
          cur =  SMS_SENT.fetchAllSENT();
    }

    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            String sender = cur.getString(5).toString();
            sender = sender.replace(" ", "");
            String date = cur.getString(2).toString();
            String msg = cur.getString(3).toString();
            String type = cur.getString(4).toString();
            String read = cur.getString(6).toString();
            String senderAddress = cur.getString(1).toString();
            senderAddress = senderAddress.replace(" ", "");
            String NombreContacto = contactUtil.getContactName(sender);

            SMS m = new SMS(senderAddress, date, msg, type, sender, read, sentStatus, NombreContacto);

            sender = FUN.formateaTlf(sender);


            if (!listasms.contains(sender)) {
                listsms.add(m);
            }          
        }
    }
```

Método `fetchAllINBOX()`:

```
public Cursor fetchAllINBOX() {
    SQLiteDatabase localSQLiteDatabase = this.database;
    String[] arrayOfString = new String[12];
    arrayOfString[0] = "_id";
    arrayOfString[1] = "ADDRESS";
    arrayOfString[2] = "DATE";
    arrayOfString[3] = "BODY";
    arrayOfString[4] = "TYPE";
    arrayOfString[5] = "NUMBER";
    arrayOfString[6] = "READ";
    arrayOfString[7] = "SENT";
    arrayOfString[8] = "NAME";


    return localSQLiteDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, arrayOfString, null, null, null, null, null);
```

y a pesar de que tan solo tengo unos 300 registros, me aparece en el log del

trabajo

> Skipped 297 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its
>   main thread.

La cuestión es que no se que puedo hacer para optimizar esta carga, ya que la pantalla desde donde llamo a eso se queda en negro y tarda unos 8 segundos en presentarse.

He intentado hacerlo en un hilo secundario, pero lo único que consigo es reducir a 5 segundos.

Una vez tengo la lista cargada lo que hago es que a través de un adapter presento la pantalla.

Alguien podría indicarme algún método para optimizar esta carga???

o indicarme como podría llegar a encontrar cual es el procedimiento que realmente sobrecarga el hilo?????

Muchas gracias

Comment: Bienvenida al sitio Martruchagr! gracias por realizar el [tour], para más información acerca de como obtener mejores respuestas te recomiendo revisar [ask]. En cuanto a tu pregunta , tu método getMessges() lo llamas dentro de un método asincrono? Es importante expliques donde llamas este método. Que realizan los métodos fetchAllINBOX y fetchAllSENT

Comment: Hola Jorgesys, muchas gracias por tu pronta respuesta.

Comment: Los metodos fetchAllIBOX y fetchAllSENT lo que hacen es devolver un cursor con todos los datos de las tablas SMS_INBOX o SMS_SENT. Esté metodo se llama desde la carga de la pantalla. Tengo una pantalla con dos TABS una para SMS Recibidos y otra para SMS Enviados. en la carga de cada uno de los tabs llamo al metodo getMessages().

Comment: Generalmente el proceso más lento en lo que realiza tu código es al obtener los datos para el cursor, agrega por favor estos métodos.

Comment: El método es el mismo, solo cambia el nombre de la tabla

Comment: @Marruchagr las actualizaciones se realizan mediante el botón [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/108609/edit) , ya agregue el código.

Comment: gracias @Jorgesys

Answer (score 2):

Lo que necesitas es ejecutar la tarea asincronamente

```
public class TareaAsincrona extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {


public GestorMailAsincrono(Context _con) {
    con =_con;

}



@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {

    //Aqui va la tarea larga
    return "1";//retornas algo para saber que se hizo la tarea
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
//Lo que quierea hacer antes de iniciar la tarea
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    if(s.equals("1"))//recibes lo que enviaste
    {
        //lo que quieres hacer al terminar la tarea
    }
      super.onPostExecute(s);
    }


}
```

Espero que te sea de ayuda.

Comment: Gracias Alvaro Fabian M por tu respuesta. He implementado lo que me has aconsejado y ahora la verdad es que tarda bastante menos (+1s464ms), ya no se queda la actividad en negro y es un tiempo aceptable de espera.  Muchas gracias

Answer (score -1):

Primeramente es muy importante cerrar los cursores después de utilizarlos

```
 public void getMessges(final List<SMS> listsms, final String tableName) {

    int count = 0;
    Cursor cur = null;

    if(tableName == "SMS_INBOX"){
          cur =  SMS_INBOX.fetchAllINBOX();
    }
    if(tableName == "SMS_SENT"){
          cur =  SMS_SENT.fetchAllSENT();
    }

    try {

    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            String sender = cur.getString(5).toString();
            sender = sender.replace(" ", "");
            String date = cur.getString(2).toString();
            String msg = cur.getString(3).toString();
            String type = cur.getString(4).toString();
            String read = cur.getString(6).toString();
            String senderAddress = cur.getString(1).toString();
            senderAddress = senderAddress.replace(" ", "");
            String NombreContacto = contactUtil.getContactName(sender);

            SMS m = new SMS(senderAddress, date, msg, type, sender, read, sentStatus, NombreContacto);

            sender = FUN.formateaTlf(sender);


            if (!listasms.contains(sender)) {
                listsms.add(m);
            }          
        }


    } finally {
        cur.close();
    }

    }
```

En cuanto a los métodos `fetchAllINBOX()` y `fetchAllSENT()` únicamnte obtén los campos de los cuales necesitas información, no es necesario obtener todos.